# Why can converting numbers to characters change the numbers?

Tags: r, string, data-structures, numeric

I imagine this has to do with R's data structures and the answer will be quick, but I haven't yet found one so here goes:

```
as.character(9875987598759875)
[1] "9875987598759876"

library(crayon)
chr(9875987598759875)
[1] "9875987598759876"

toString(9875987598759875)
[1] "9875987598759876"
```

What gives? How should I be making this conversion more safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Machine$integer.max` indicates that the largest integer R can store is 2147483647 (this could *conceivably* vary across platforms, but it's very unlikely to). Any number larger than that is automatically converted to floating point, with the attendant imprecision/round-off error. (Unlike in Python, which expensively but magically converts integer variables to an arbitrary-length representation as necessary.)

*If* you install the `bit64` package you can use 64-bit integers, with (presumably) exactness up to

```
print(2^63-1,digits=22)
[1] 9223372036854775808
```

If you *start* with a character string, you can safely do round-trip conversion to `integer64` and back:

```
library(bit64)
cc <- "9875987598759875"
x <- as.integer64(cc)
identical(cc,as.character(x))
## [1] TRUE
```

However, typically once you've read a number into R as a regular number it's too late. You can use `colClasses="integer64"` with `read.table()`/`read.csv()`/etc. to read values in as `integer64`; I believe the file-reading functions from `readr` and `data.table` also have integer64-handling capabilities.

For many applications, if you're not actually planning on doing anything numerical with these digit-strings, it's safest and easiest to make sure you import them as `character` in the first place ...

Comment: Great, this pretty much covers it! Figured it would be something like this.